# Network dropout same time daily

Tags: networking, server

I will start with adding I am new to Linux and server management, I am self teaching to host a few game servers on the cheap.

I am having issues where my network drops out daily at roughly the same time, approx. 2:45 am and wont reconnect what ever I do until 5:50 am, I have tried multiple restarts of both my server and router.

I was wondering if anyone couple point me to what could be going on as a pointer on what to look for.

My setup:

I have a Dell Poweredge R710.
Ubuntu 19.04.
Internal static IP set at router side.
External Static IP set with a Static IP VPN service.

My Network layout:

Netgear Orbi Mesh → Netgear Unmanaged Switch → Server, all connections with Cat6 or 5e cable.

The only thing server side I could think of was possibly a bad cron job, but I can't see anything in any users crontab files, only 1 cron job running. Could it be something with OpenVPN?

I have had a Google and can't seem to find anything similar to this.

Update: I think I have found the issue, I have found that whenever my SkyQ box goes into sleep mode at 2:45am it discounects my server until it comes back online at 5:50am, now I am at a loss on how to fix it.

Comment: Is it just the one computer that loses connectivity or is it all? Can you ping the Orbi from the computer when it is down? Is there anything suspicious on the Orbi in Advanced->Router Status?

Comment: Its just the 1 system going down, the system is headless, when it discontects I can't gain access to it, and at the times its down its hard for me to get to it and check.

I was thinking maybe I can setup an auto ping hourly, I dont know how to do that but will work it out

Comment: `journalctl -a --since="YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"` may help diagnose too.

Comment: I would check the syslog, by default network errors would go in that log file. `less /var/log/syslog` and then go to the end (End key). Then search going up for something suspicious. If you see something in regard to the network, feel free to edit your post and add that there.